# Work manager if connected to WFI and connected to cellular network

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

In my application, I want to upload files to a server. There are 400- 500 files are there, I am using work manager to upload files on a server. If a user is connected to WIFI I want to upload a single file after every 15 min and if a user is not connected to WIFI but cellular data is present then I want to upload a single file after every 6 hrs to a server. For this I had written following condition is it ok or should I have to make changes for better performance.

```
PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder wifiWorkBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FileUpload.class, 15,
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.UNMETERED).build());

        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder mobileDataWorkBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(FileUpload.class, 6,
                        TimeUnit.HOURS)
                        .setConstraints(new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.METERED).build());

        PeriodicWorkRequest wifiWork = wifiWorkBuilder.build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest mobileDataWork = mobileDataWorkBuilder.build();
        //WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(wifiWork);
        //WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(mobileDataWork);
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("wifiJob", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,wifiWork);
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("mobileDataJob", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,mobileDataWork);
```